# PHPExcel incorrectly defines the MSO word files format.

Tags: phpexcel

I'm use PHPExcel v. 1.7.8 and I trying run this code:

```
$PHPReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filename);
$class = get_class($PHPReader);
```

When I run this code for MSO .doc file, I get $classname = 'PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5'.
It's wrong! How do I correct check the file format?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Either modify the read() method of the classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLERead.php file to include additional checks above and beyond the check that this is simply an OLE2 file - e.g. parsing the Workbook Global substream (0x0005) checking for the existence of an XLS_Type_SHEET (0x0085) record; or don't pass a .doc file to the reader.

Comment: Why these checks were not included in PHPExcel distro?

Comment: Because I didn't write them.... I simply didn't think that people would try to load .doc files using PHPExcel